# React How to destruct deep props in constructor?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, destructuring

I have the following constructor in my class component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dirty: this.props.form.dirty // error happens here!
    };
  }
```

`eslint` returns an error for destructing the props. How is it possible for deeper props like this?

Comment: because is the constructor you do not have access to this.propsm instead try `props.form.dirty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a error per se. But you could use something like this to avoid the warning.

```
const { dirty } = props.form;
this.state = { dirty };
```

OR

```
const { form: { dirty } } = props;
this.state = { dirty };
```

Comment: Yeah you are right but is it ok to define a const on constructor ?

Comment: Yes. Why not? :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `this.props` inside constructor as you are getting `props` as an argument.
Secondly for destructuring, you could do something like this:

```
const {form: {dirty = 'any initial value in case of undefined'}} = props;
this.setState = {
   dirty
}
```